# How to build my own SDK like mADServer?

Tags: android, sdk

I am looking for build my own SDK. I had searched a lot but I cant get clear idea about how to build my own SDK and later I need to integrate it to my project. How can I build my own SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple Jar would be sufficient. You create a Jar with your classes and then your user adds that Jar to his project and so he can use your classes. The AdMob SDK is done that way.

Comment: can you suggest me some tutorials or samples please

Answer (score 0):

You have to let your code be  Library project.

**To create a library project**, set the Mark this project as library flag in the Android project generation wizard.

[image]

or if your project is already generated, you can right click in the project, and then in properties, and check the Is Library option:

[image]

**To use such a library**, in the project you want to use it right-click on it and select properties. On the Android tab add the library project to it.

[image]

**Instead of this last part**, you can take the generated **jar** of your library porject, and put it in the **libs** folder of your target project.

You have a complete tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

(where i took the images from )

Comment: Hi I am looking to create SDK like Google AdMob SDK...and if user integrate it, He can access ads with 2 or 3 line simple code. Is it possible via creating library projects as you mentioned ???

Comment: then can you please provide some sample code to learn the basics..am new to android

Comment: follow the link, it is a complete tutorial